# fastest way to insert/update element in the List

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I want to replace one object within the provided list or add it if not already in this list. I need the **fastest** way to do this insert/update.

I have two versions. Which is faster or do you know a faster way?

**version 1:**

```
void update(List<Task> orderedTask, Task task) {
        int idx = Collections.binarySearch(orderedTask, task);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            orderedTask.remove(idx);
            orderedTask.add(idx, task);
        } else {
            orderedTask.add(-idx - 1, task);
        }
    }
```

**version 2:**

```
void update2(List<Task> orderedTask, Task task) {
        var idx = orderedTask.indexOf(task);
        if(idx >= -1) {
            orderedTask.remove(idx);
            orderedTask.add(idx, task);
        }
        else {
            orderedTask.add(-idx - 1, task);
        }
    }
```

I guess, java streams are not faster than the methods above..

Comment: Why not use `Set`?

Comment: because I must **retain the ordering**. And I dont know if LinkedHashSet would be better for such cases..

Comment: LinkedHashMap or LinkedHashSet, it will retain order. List is very slow for searching and you need to do one.

Comment: And what is `orders` in the `update2` method? Probably a typo?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea yes, but using ArrayList has better performance for insertions and sorting..

Comment: you mean orderedTask..means that it is a list which is ordered.

Comment: `orders.indexOf(task)` I can't see `orders` defined anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: @nimo23 you mentioned you need ordering not sorting. I don't see an issue with adding and removing from a HashSet. TreeSet on the other hand is very costly in those operations.

Comment: @nimo23 Yes you're right. `ArrayList` provides faster insertions but it is not known for having distinct elements. To check for duplicates you need to iterate over it (which might prove to be a costly operation), `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` are meant to be used for that purpose.

Comment: The list can have duplicates..I dont have to check for that..It is okay if only the first element is replaced.

Comment: I only need the **fastest way** for LIST-Implementations as described in my question.

Comment: @nimo23 Both of your methods are removing the duplicate elements. What do you think `orderedTask.remove(idx)` performs under the hood? It is a lot costlier.

Comment: BinarySearch is faster than indexOf()
check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495416/indexof-or-binary-search

Comment: @agupta thanks that answers my question. As I use `ArrayList`, the specified list implements the `RandomAccess` interface..so I can use `binarySearch()`. I guess, there is nothing faster than `binarySearch` for `List`. **So the solution above is the fastest possible for `List`-interface.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first focus on correctness rather than performance.

You second method

```
void update2(List<Task> orderedTask, Task task) {
    var idx = orderedTask.indexOf(task);
    if(idx >= -1) {
        orderedTask.remove(idx);
        orderedTask.add(idx, task);
    }
    else {
        orderedTask.add(-idx - 1, task);
    }
}
```

is broken, as for some unknown reason you changed the condition `idx >= 0` of the first variant to `idx >= -1`, so the code will attempt to change an element at the invalid index `-1` when no matching element is in the list.

When you fix this issue by using `idx >= 0`, you will face the problem that `indexOf` will always return `-1` when it didn’t find a matching element, which does not allow to derive an insertion position. The formula `-idx - 1` is only valid for search methods specifying it in their contract, like `binarySearch`, but not for `indexOf`.

Since `indexOf` returns `-1` for elements not in the list, the formula will always evaluate to zero, hence you’re inserting new elements always at the beginning of the list. If your contract is to keep the list sorted, you’re not fulfilling it. Besides that, always inserting at the beginning is very inefficient for implementations like `ArrayList`.

If your contract is that you receive a sorted list and have to keep it sorted, `binarySearch` is the only way to fulfill the contract and, well, it’s more efficient than `indexOf` too. But when you care for performance when dealing with an `ArrayList`, you should not use `orderedTask.remove(idx); orderedTask.add(idx, task);` to replace an element. `remove(int index)` has to copy all remaining elements in the backing array whereas `add(int index, …)` has to copy them back to their original position. Just use the `set` method instead.

```
void update(List<Task> orderedTask, Task task) {
    int idx = Collections.binarySearch(orderedTask, task);
    if (idx >= 0) {
        orderedTask.set(idx, task);
    } else {
        orderedTask.add(-idx - 1, task);
    }
}
```